# What are the Best Practices for Developing Content for a Product-Promotion Website?

Tags: publishing, copyright, websites, content-strategy

For products that are already listed in marketplace, what would be the best practice in sourcing content for a blog-style website that reviews, compares, and promotes such listed products with a view to (1) generating more traffic for the products in the marketplace, where they are originally listed (2) helping my website visitors narrow down their choice?

Basically, I will acquire the product and test it - then write a review of my experience.

The main reason for this question is to seek insights - from the perspective of product owners and from the perspective of marketplaces, in terms of the content for my website? I am interested in the best practices.

So far, I have considered two approaches but not sure if either is viable or reasonable, they are:

1. To request some product details (such as images, features) from product owner. Then write content that reviews and promotes the product, based on own experience using it.
2. To completely develop all content used to review and promote the products.

What are your thoughts on the implications of copyright and what are the best practices that comes to mind, for such website?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that info you seek exists at all, and if so is very subjective.

You would have a lot of competition from BIG sites that review MANY products and already have a base of users as well as good visibility in search engines. Think Consumer Reports,  Amazon reviews, and specialty sites that focus on very specific type of products.

Your real question should be how to start a new site and make it successful.

If you acquire the product and test then review it you do  not need users to give you details as you would already have them.

What motivation would people have to put their reviews on your site after you already reviewed it?

You would likely have better results if you focused on one type of product and did them better than competing sites.  But still you will be competing against bigger better established sites.

Copyright has no bearing if you do your own reviews.  You would need to see an IP lawyer to ensure you do not have problems should other people put comments or reviews on your site.

Comment: I am aware of the big sites. My aim is not to compete but to create a differentiating behaviour, which I can't disclose here since a new idea. For now, my question is specific to copyright ownership as I have reasonable access to biz/tech dev. From your comment, you reckon my considered approach 2 means ownership of my content but not neccessarily ownership of content contributed by site visitors, right? Just to clarify, my option 1 was to seek content such as product image from product owners (not from my site users). It's not easy to assess your comment without a name  – but many thanks.

Comment: It is very unclear just what you need access to.   You can legally take pictures of products and use them.  You can AFAIK (but verify with a lawyer) use the OEMs brochures and infos in reviews without problems.  If you ask they might give you pictures in format ready for posting or you could dl them from their website.  You need a business plan if you think you will have differentiating behaviour that will be profitable.  Try asking a more specific question about just copyright issues without the confusing info.  And yes if people post they own the copyrights unless you obtain them legally.

Comment: And as to product images they would not own rights to them any more than you would unless the OEM granted them the rights.  But you do not AFAIK (but  again verify with a lawyer) need rights to post those pictures in a review.  And you can always take your own pictures and own the rights to use them.  But CAVEAT - there might be some unique cases if they had somehow used other protections than copyright although that is rare.  You really need to see a lawyer not ask for internet opinions. Maybe you have a red hot new idea but I do not see how it could work well enough to bother doing.

Comment: I'm not sure if your answers are meant for my question since I reiterated that my question is limited to copyright of the content, depending on how the content is sourced. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: I mentioned copyright issues. do you have a more specific focused clearer question on copyright that an answer might help you with.

Comment: Thanks so much for your thoughts on my questions, which I have read with interest. Now I will continue to look forward to more thoughts, if any. Thanks once more.